# Gnome-shell broken by MenuLibre

Tags: gnome, menulibre

I used MenuLibre to create an application launcher and, after editing and saving it a few times, gnome-shell (3.10) instantly crashed. It will not restart; rebooting and logging in again simply results in a blank screen. Strangely, this is nothing to do with the (not) offending .desktop file, as deleting it with the virtual terminal does not solve the problem. I've also tried removing the gnome-shell folder in .local and the session cache folder in ~/.cache .

This problem has happened before in exactly the same situation (using MenuLibre and gnome-shell), so there is no uncertainty as to MenuLibre being the cause.

I have no idea how to access gnome's error log, so I'm asking for help with identifying the problem and restoring a usable session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have missed a more obvious configuration folder to delete. The problem was solved by deleting /home/[USERNAME]/.config/menus

```
rm -r /home/[USERNAME]/.config/menus
```